# I have several variables in a column and want to create a loop in R so I can export each variable onto it's own sheet in the same excel workbook

Tags: r, loops, dplyr

In an excel doc, I have 5 distinct string variables in a column called `Team`. The other two columns have a date and a number. I want to take each distinct string variable and create 5 sheets on the same excel worksheet in R. I know I need to do a loop but keep getting stuck. I currently am doing it the long way but think there's a cleaner way.

I got stuck using a loop so I did it the long way and it works but there has to be a shortcut.

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBkRk.png)

```
split_data <- read_excel("H:/R_split_pages.xlsx", sheet = "Sheet1")

Wildcats_ex <- split_data %>%
  filter(Team == "Wildcats")

Lions_ex <- split_data %>%
  filter(Team == "Lions")

Bulldogs_ex <- split_data %>%
  filter(Team == "Bulldogs")

Panthers_ex <- split_data %>%
  filter(Team == "Panthers")

Warriors_ex <- split_data %>%
  filter(Team == "Warriors")

write.xlsx(Wildcats_ex, file = "C:\\R_split_pagesRoutput2.xlsx", sheetName = "Wildcats", append = FALSE)

write.xlsx(Lions_ex, file = "C:\\R_split_pagesRoutput2.xlsx", sheetName = "Lions", append = TRUE)

write.xlsx(Bulldogs_ex, file = "C:\\R_split_pagesRoutput2.xlsx", sheetName = "Bulldogs", append = TRUE)

write.xlsx(Panthers_ex, file = "C:\\R_split_pagesRoutput2.xlsx", sheetName = "Panthers", append = TRUE)

write.xlsx(Warriors_ex, file = "C:\\R_split_pagesRoutput2.xlsx", sheetName = "Warriors", append = TRUE)
```

Comment: Hi there, could you add code formatting to make your question easier to read?

Answer (score 0):

functions are made for this sort of repetitive task. Without a data example this is a little difficult to test, but this should work:

```
library(dplyr)
excel_func <- function(x){
  split_data %>%
    filter(Team == x) %>% 
    write.xlsx(file = "C:\\R_split_pagesRoutput2.xlsx", sheetName = x, append = TRUE)
}
```

... then you can use:

```
function("Lions")
```

to write the tab to the excel file.  If you have a vector with all the team names in (say `teams_vec`), you can work through and write them all with `lapply` and write the tabs in one go:

```
lapply(teams_vec, excel_func)
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider `split` + `lapply` or `by`:

```
team_data <- read_excel("H:/R_split_pages.xlsx", sheet = "Sheet1")

my_file <- "C:\\R_split_pagesRoutput2.xlsx"
if file.exists(my_file) unlink(my_file)

team_dfs <- split(team_data, team_data$Team)

lapply(team_dfs, function(df) 
      write.xlsx(file = my_file, sheetName = df$Team[1], append = TRUE)
)
```

Alternatively:

```
by(team_data, team_data$Team, function(df) 
      write.xlsx(file = my_file, sheetName = df$Team[1], append = TRUE)
)
```